# GetWindowText() returning empty string and strange error

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using the following code inside a global CBT hook procedure:

```
TCHAR title[256];
int getT = GetWindowText(hWnd, title, 256);
if (getT == 0) {
    int err = GetLastError();
    logFile << "Error GetWindowText(): " << err << endl;
} else {
    logFile << "getT = " << getT << endl;
}
```

The problem is that for certain windows the GetWindowText() function works just fine and I get the correct window title, but for some others it returns 0 and I get an empty string. The GetLastError() returns 183 which is ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS:

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

The error is not random: I always get it with the same kind of window opened by the same application, but for all the other windows it seems to work fine.

Comment: Are you attempting to retrieve the text of an edit control in another application?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the title of a window

Comment: Is this a window we will have on our systems that we can test against?

Comment: No, unless you're an online poker player. It's a PokerStars poker table window. I can get the other windows from PokerStars just fine (main window for example) but when I open the table I get this error.

Comment: Try to call `SetLastError(666)` before calling `GetWindowText`. If you will start getting 666 back, it may mean `GetWindowText` is intercepted with an api hook which prevents reading a certain window and doesn't bother setting a proper error code.

Comment: Yes! I'm getting back 666 as error. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe their table windows is an edit control, just modified enough to appear as a regular window. Or it might be just mimicing a real window and not using SetWindowText() at all. What does Spy++ tell you about the window?

Comment: Mmm... I fired up Spy++ but since it's the first time I use it I cannot really tell what information could be useful to me. What should I look for in particular? (Edit: if it's useful, it can tell me the correct window caption successfully)

Comment: Incidentally, trying to hook into a poker game sounds suspicious. Are you attempting to hack and cheat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not have the rights to retrieve text from certain windows on Windows Vista and above.

My guess is that ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS comes from your log file when you print "Error GetWindowText(): ". You should get the error code first before doing anything else.

Another possibility is that the window returns 0 from its `WM_GETTEXT` handler without setting the last error. As `GetWindowText` documentation states, if you call it on a window belonging to the same process, it retrieves the text by sending this message. Since you are calling the function from a hook, you might be in the same process.

Comment: Edited the code to retrieve the error before writing on file, and it still returns the same strange error. Also, I'm on Win XP.

Comment: You are calling this from a hook, right? If the window is in the same process, then window text is retrieved by sending the WM_GETTEXT message, which might be returning 0 without setting the last error. Would GetLastError return 183, if you call it *before* GetWindowText?

Comment: After over 10 years, here I am hitting this same issue. To debug, I called `SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS)` right before the call to `GetWindowText()` to ensure it is clear, and the result is that, as the window handle points to own process, `WM_GETTEXT` gets called, returns a zero-length string, and never really updates the last error (as there was no last error anyway).